# Ubuntu 17.10 frequently freezing

Tags: gnome, 17.10, freeze

I have recently switched from windows 10 to ubuntu 17.10.
I'm using a 2.5GHz core i5 4GB RAM asus k53e laptop. The problem is that I have noticed that ubuntu suddenly stops working and the screen freezes. I don't run programs that do heavy tasks, only browsing (chrome) and word editing (libreoffice). I have to restart the laptop each time this happens. Any solutions for the problem?

Thanks,

Comment: Instability is almost always a driver issue.

Comment: I had the same problem on an old Dell workstation, however I also had a nvidia quadro gpu on it. Ubuntu 17.10 kept freezing after sometime (10 minutes or so). I switched to 16.04 LTS  and it was fine afterwards.